# How to prevent recreating activity which has AsyncTask and Service in it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Let's assume I have 2 activities: Activity 1, Activity 2. I am starting Activity 2 from Activity 1. Activity 2 - is activity with image and progress bar to display the progress of executing some background task in it which is started in service.

When I try to press hardware Back button from Activity 2 it brings me back to Activity 1, so I can start Activity 2 again even if there is service still running.

So the question is such: How can I prevent such behaviour. I need to start Activity 2 only 1 time and not exit from it while the work is not finished?? And another case is that I can stop my application from Task manager, but service will be working and after that I can run application again - with new service, while old will be still running? What mechanisms are there to prevent such behaviour? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to a local service from your `Activity` class when it is starting up. Once bound, your `Activity` can call any public methods declared by that service. This would allow your `Activity` to bind to the service, then check to see if the service is currently doing any work. You might make a method like `isRunning()` or similar. If the service is not currently doing any work, you might want to start a new job. If it is already executing some task, you could then display the current progress of that task.

You should read the [Local Service Sample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) article on the Android developer site to get an idea how to do this.